# javascript keyup fired in INPUT when ENTER pressed in BUTTON

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this case:

- 1 input
- 1 button

Using the jquery, I bind:

- input.keyup = intercept the ENTER press and "alert" a message
- button.click = just focus the input

To reproduce the BUG, focus on the button (not clicking, use TAB key) and press ENTER.

Result: the button will focus the input and the input will fire the alert.

I already tried to bind the keyup/keydown/keypress in the button and call then "event.stopPropagation()" but without success.

Ps.: I'm using Chrome 85.0.4183.83

```
<h4>Just press ENTER on the button focused!</h4>
<input type="text">
<button type="button">OK</button>


$(document).ready(() => {
  let btn = $('button');
  btn.bind('click', () => $('input').focus());
  btn.bind('keyup', ev => ev.stopPropagation());
  btn.bind('keydown', ev => ev.stopPropagation());
  btn.bind('keypress', ev => ev.stopPropagation());
  //btn.focus();
  
  $('input').bind('keyup', (ev) => {
    if (ev.keyCode == 13) {
        alert('This message appears when ENTER is pressed in input !');
      }
  })
});
```

https://codepen.io/betonetotbo/full/bGpvQGq

How can I solve this, and prevent the keyup to be trigged on the input while I just press ENTER on the button to perform the click event?

I think this behavior is because the `click` event in button is fired at the `keydown` event by key ENTER, and at my case on the click event I change the focus to the input so this results on the `keyup` event at the input.

Comment: If you're okay with using keypress vs keyup that seems to fix the issue.  Though, I'm not sure what your end goal is.

Answer (score -1):

The alert is being triggered because your code preventing the event propagation is against the button's keyup event while your code displaying the alert is bound to the text input field.

Answer (score -2):

when the button is in focus and `Enter` is pressed it's triggering the button's click handler in turn focusing the input. So `Enter` *keyup* event is fired when the input is in focus.

If you change the *keyup* event on the input to ***keypress*** or ***keydown*** this issue will not occur.

Comment: If I use `keypress` and keep the ENTER pressed after the click handled the alert message also appears. If I use the `keydown` and also keep the ENTER pressed the alert message algo will appear. So this is not a solution.